# How do I call ediff-regions-wordwise programmatically?

Tags: ediff

I want to compare two regions of the same buffer (it's the output from test failures).  It looks something like this:

```
Some header lines
{
  ...expected body
}, but was
{
  ...actual body
}
Some footer lines
```

I'm trying to write a little function that I can call after copying the test output, but I'm getting hung up on calling `ediff-regions-wordwise` in the script.  The documentation doesn't list the regions as parameters, only the buffers.  I can pretty easily figure out the starting and ending positions for both regions, but how do I communicate that to `ediff-regions-wordwise`?  I don't want to have to select them every time since finding them just requires a couple of traversal commands.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info